# Getting CST time for asian timezone

Tags: java, timezone

Why am I getting wrong timezone output for this code? The timestamp is correct (2:30 AM), but why am I getting CST as timezone format?

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a (zz)")
        .withZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai").toZoneId());
 
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong("1655490600000"))));
```

Comment: Because China Standard Time is the name of the timezone?

Comment: Time zone abbreviations like `CST` are most often ambiguous, the same abbreviation is used for several unrelated time zones. CST may be for Australian Central Standard Time, China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time or North American Central Standard Time. So you have got the correct and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2-4 letter pseudo-zones commonly used for localized presentation of time zones are not standardized. They are not even unique, as you seem to have noticed.

- “CST” means “China Standard Time” in Asia for zones such as "Asia/Shanghai”.
- “CST” means “Central Standard Time” in North America for time zones such as “America/Chicago”.
- “CST” also means [“Cuba Standard Time”](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst-cuba).

Use these 2-4 letter codes only for localized presentation to the user. Never use them for data storage or data exchange.

Another thing: Do not use `TimeZone` class. That is one of the legacy date-time classes. Use only date-time classes from the *java.time* package. Specifically replaced by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`.

In the following code, `Instant .ofEpochMilli` returns a `Instant`. The `atZone` call returns a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant
.ofEpochMilli(
    Long
    .parseLong( "1655490600000" )
)
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Shanghai" )
)
.toString()
```

> 2022-06-18T02:30+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]